# PhpSpreadsheet outputs encrypted text instead of starting the download

Tags: php, slim, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I'm creating an API with slimframework and I have a route where I'm trying to export data to an excel file and download it instead of saving it but when I try to do it it outputs text like this `��ࡱ�;�`, the thing is that I have three ways of getting data (different sql queries) and only one fails, could anyone explain me why?

This is one of the arrays that works perfectly:

```
Array
(
       [0] => Array
          (
            [id_asistente] => 1
            [nombre] => adfadsfas
            [inst_procedencia] => sadfsa
            [perfil_academico] => asdfasdf
            [estado] => asdfsaf
            [correo] => mail@gmail.com
            [cursos_inscritos] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_asistente] => 2
            [nombre] => asdfsafsaf
            [inst_procedencia] => asdfasfsa
            [perfil_academico] => asdfasdfsdf
            [estado] => sdfdsafadfs
            [correo] => mailll@gmail.com
            [cursos_inscritos] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_asistente] => 3
            [nombre] => asdfasfsfa
            [inst_procedencia] => asdffds
            [perfil_academico] => asdfasdfdsaf
            [estado] => asdfasdf
            [correo] => edu@gmail.com
            [cursos_inscritos] => 0
        )

    )
```

And this is the array that, I don't know why, it doesn't work:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_asistente] => 2
        [nombre] => asdasdasdad
        [inst_procedencia] => Asda
        [perfil_academico] => asdasd
        [estado] => asdass
        [correo] => mailll@gmail.com
        [asistencia] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_asistente] => 4
        [nombre] => Aasdasdad
        [inst_procedencia] => asdsa
        [perfil_academico] => asdasd
        [estado] => asdasdas
        [correo] => asdasdsa@adasdsa.com
        [asistencia] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_asistente] => 6
        [nombre] => asdasdas
        [inst_procedencia] => asdasd
        [perfil_academico] => asdasd
        [estado] => asddas
        [correo] => asdasdsa@gmail.com
        [asistencia] => 1
    )
)
```

And this is the function where I try to download the file:

```
function exportToExcel($data, $filename) {
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->fromArray($data, NULL, 'A1');

    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $writer->save('php://output');
}
```

To be honest I don't know if it has something to do with the array but I can't think of another reason, any help would be appreciated.